# mulitple json file as inputs throws error for building dashboard

Tags: terraform

My main.tf looks like this, Im trying to pass mulitple json files as input into the dashboard resource but running into an error

```
locals{
  json_file = fileset(path.module, "dash/*.json")
  json_data  = {
    for files in local.json_file : files => jsondecode(file(files))
  }
}

resource "google_monitoring_dashboard" "dashboards" {
  for_each = local.json_data
  project  = var.monitoring_project
  dashboard_json = local.json_data
}
```

I get the following error

```
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│
│   on dashboard.tf line 12, in resource "google_monitoring_dashboard" "usecase_dashboards":
│   12:   dashboard_json = local.json_data
│     ├────────────────
│     │ local.json_data is object with 1 attribute "dash/airflow-dashboard.json"
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "dashboard_json": string required.
```

Comment: Can you try with `for_each = fileset(path.module, "dash/*.json")`?

Comment: no, same error....

Comment: Ah, sorry, try `dashboard_json = each.value` with the above change.

Comment: │ Error: "dashboard_json" contains an invalid JSON: invalid character 'd' looking for beginning of value
│
│   with google_monitoring_dashboard.usecase_dashboards["dash/airflow-dashboard.json"],
│   on dashboard.tf line 18, in resource "google_monitoring_dashboard" "usecase_dashboards":
│   18:   dashboard_json = each.value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out

```
locals{
  json_file = fileset(path.module, "dash/*.json")
}

resource "google_monitoring_dashboard" "usecase_dashboards" {
  for_each = local.json_file
  project  = var.monitoring_project
  dashboard_json =file(each.key)
}
```

Thanks @marko-e, Your comments provided the hint...